# Trying converting registry code to Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows, registry

I am trying to convert this registry code to my vb.net code... and having some trouble!

Here is the registry code:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\worldoftanks.exe\PerfOptions]
"CpuPriorityClass"=dword:00000003
```

This code makes the application "worldoftanks.exe" run at high priority at launch.

Here is my Vb.net code:

```
 Try
        Dim regKey As RegistryKey
        regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\worldoftanks.exe\PerfOptions", True)
        regKey.SetValue("CpuPriorityClass", 3, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
        regKey.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

For some reason I am receiving this error:

```
The specified RegistryKeyPermissionCheck value is invalid. Parameter name: mode
```

This is my first time dealing with registry through vb.net! If someone could help, that would be awesome!

Comment: Hmm... I cannot see what is wrong with it o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your line to this:
EDIT:  There was an extra backslash in front of Software... it's been removed

```
regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\worldoftanks.exe\PerfOptions", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryOptions.None)
```

Comment: I was hoping it would create this part of the registry: \worldoftanks.exe\PerfOptions but instead it tells me that the specified path is invalid.

Comment: Oh... What part of it does exist?  All the way up to the exe?

Comment: I edited the other comment... I accidentally pressed "enter". Before I finished it.

Comment: I edited the answer... there was an extra backslash infront of the "software".. it is not needed

Comment: YAY! Glad to see that.  If you are planning to compile this for others to use... make sure they know they will need admin rights (possibly have to "run as admin" also) or they will get denied.

Comment: :) the program requires admin rights on run. So it's all good! Again, thank you.